# What is better to use for creating layouts. Java or XML?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to `Android` and am working on a new application.

I've created some layouts in the `XML` document which happens to be quite large. I know that I can save a lot of space if I create my layouts with `Java` loops, but on the other hand layout is something that I won't probably need to change very often.

What is better performance wise? `Java` code or the `XML` layout?

Comment: XML is pre-compiled and translated to a binary format. There will be no remarkable performance-difference. Use whatever you find more comfortable or a combination of both.

Comment: @LukasKnuth You should post that as an answer, since it sounds like a pretty good one.

Comment: @Michael question is closed. Also, comment is fine here.

Comment: Seems like a perfectly reasonable question that can be answered objectively. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Personally, I think this should stay closed (though, as "not constructive"); Java is more used for dynamic layouts whereas XML is used for static ones, but both can be used in many ways and it's entirely subjective and up to the programmer to decide how to use them.

Comment: Why don't we discuss the pros and cons?

Comment: And of course there is Android automatically choosing layouts for you based on screen size, density, etc. when using XML. Perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time I prefer `layout XML resource` files, but it varies according to the need.

1. First, the resource sets (e.g., `res/layout-land/` in addition to `res/layout/`) allow you to define multiple UIs to be used in different circumstances.

   - layout-land -> for landscape
   - layout-port -> for portrait
   - layout-v15 -> for android version >= 15
   - layout-sw600dp -> for screens with a certain width
2. Second, there are tools that can help you create those layout resources successfully. drag-and-drop GUI building of Eclipse is one of them.
3. Third, it tends to be more terse, so if you're typing this stuff by hand, the XML will be less typing.
4. In Java code you have to compile & run the code to see how the layout looks like, while in XML (if you are using eclipse) you can see it directly with the tools that eclipse provides.

For everything static I use XML, because it is easy to find in the structure of your project.

But in some cases, you want to create dynamic layouts and you have no other choice then to use Java Code. Be smart, in this, so if you have to add several Views that look the same do this

> From my perspective, `xml layouts` are good if you want android to
>   handle the layouts automatically. This would be for things like
>   **data-entry type applications (like banking applications)**. Java layouts
>   would be better for applications that need tight control of the UI
>   (like angry birds)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a really good answer. But what will work faster? Layout created by XML or Java?

Comment: I dont think there might be any performance differenece between the two. But it is much easier and _faster_ for you to work on xml(see 2nd and 4th point). Mostly it is preferred to use xml layouts, but it entirely depends on you. But if you are getting data dynamically and setting it in separate layouts, then you could use java layouts. Also java layouts are preferred mostly in Gaming applications, where you need much tight control of the UI.